# Calculate Complex Limit

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $W$ is analytic in a domain $D$.  Let $z_0$ be fixed with $W'(z_0) \ne 0$ and let $f$ be defined for all $z \in D-{z_0}$,

$$f(z) = \frac{W'(z_0)W'(z)}{(W(z)-W(z_0))^2} - \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^2}$$

Prove that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ and calculate $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) $ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand as a Taylor series $$\frac{W(z) - W(z_0)}{z-z_0} = W'(z_0) + \frac{W''(z_0)}{2} (z-z_0) + \frac{W'''(z_0)}{6}(z-z_0)^2...,$$ which can be inverted (since $W'(z_0) \ne 0$) to give $$\frac{z-z_0}{W(z) - W(z_0)} = W'(z_0)^{-1} - \frac{W''(z_0)}{2 W'(z_0)^2} (z-z_0) + \frac{\frac{W''(z_0)^2}{4} - \frac{W'(z_0)W'''(z_0)}{6}}{W'(z_0)^3} (z-z_0)^2 + ...,$$ so $$\frac{1}{W(z) - W(z_0)} = W'(z_0)^{-1} (z-z_0)^{-1} - \frac{W''(z_0)}{2 W'(z_0)^2} + \frac{3W''(z_0)^2 - 2W'(z_0)W'''(z_0)}{12W'(z_0)^3} (z-z_0) + ...$$ and after differentiating and multiplying by $W'(z_0)$, $$-\frac{W'(z)W'(z_0)}{(W(z) - W(z_0))^2} = - \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^2} + \frac{3W''(z_0)^2 - 2W'(z_0)W'''(z_0)}{12W'(z_0)^3} + ...$$ showing that your limit should be $$\frac{2W'(z_0)W'''(z_0) - 3W''(z_0)^2}{12W'(z_0)^3}.$$